# Scale up Item in RecyclerView to overlaps 2 adjacent items Android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm using RecyclerView with GridLayoutManager. The goal I want to achieve is when I click on an item, It'll scale up and overlaps the adjacent items. Just like the picture below (in Android TV)
[image]

When the onClick event is triggered, I call

```
v.animate().scaleX(1.2f).scaleY(1.2f).setDuration(500).start();
```

But the result is below:
[image]

It can overlaps only items that has position lower than itself.
What should I do to overlaps all of the adjacent items. Thanks in advance.
**EDIT**
I already tried:

```
v.bringToFront();
```

or

```
(v.getParent()).bringChildToFront(v);
```

But both of them don't work.

Comment: Have you solved the problem? i faced the same problem, thx.

Comment: Use `Carousel`. It is best suited for this requirement..!!..Refer : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/146145/Android-3D-Carousel

Comment: Have you found any solution?

Answer (score 6):

According **aga's** answer, i use **ViewCompat.setElevation(View view, float elevation)** to support API prior to 21, It works like a charming.

```
static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

  public ViewHolder(View root) {
    // bind views
    // ...

    // bind focus listener
    root.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
      @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
          if (hasFocus) {
            // run scale animation and make it bigger

            ViewCompat.setElevation(root, 1);
          } else {
            // run scale animation and make it smaller

            ViewCompat.setElevation(root, 0);
          }
        }
     });
  }
}
```

The item layout file is very simple like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:background="@drawable/sl_live_item" />
```

Comment: Can you share your layout file? I already used ViewCompat.setElevation() but it doesn't help...

Comment: no.useless.ViewCompat not do anything below 21.
   public static void setElevation(@NonNull View view, float elevation) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
            view.setElevation(elevation);
        }
    }

Answer (score 2):

1.Override the getChildDrawingOrder method.

```
@Override
protected int getChildDrawingOrder(int childCount, int i) {
    View view = getLayoutManager().getFocusedChild();
    if (null == view) {
        return super.getChildDrawingOrder(childCount, i);
    }
    int position = indexOfChild(view);

    if (position < 0) {
        return super.getChildDrawingOrder(childCount, i);
    }
    if (i == childCount - 1) {
        return position;
    }
    if (i == position) {
        return childCount - 1;
    }
    return super.getChildDrawingOrder(childCount, i);
}
```

2.RecyclerView **setChildrenDrawingOrderEnabled** is **true**.

```
setChildrenDrawingOrderEnabled(true);
```

3.When item view has focus, **invalidate** its parent.

```
@Override
public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
    if (hasFocus) {
        v.setScaleX(1.5f);
        v.setScaleY(1.5f);
        mRecyclerView.invalidate();
    } else {
        v.setScaleX(1.0f);
        v.setScaleY(1.0f);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can also use `recyclerview.setChildDrawingOrderCallback` without inherit and override `recyclerview` methods.

Comment: @ramineftekhari Precisely!

Comment: This method still overlaps the next view on the currently focused item. The goal is to make current item overlap the others.

Answer (score 0):

Try to invoke `v.bringToFront()` before running the animation.
If it doesn't work another variant is to use `View#setElevation(float val)` where val > 0. The drawback is that you'll need to set elevation back to 0 when you're deselecting the item.

Comment: It works. But View#setElevation(float val) requires API 21. My application also supports API 15. Are there other ways to solve it. Thanks

Comment: @HuyDuongTu you can check my answer which uses ViewCompat.setElevation(View view, float elevation) to support API prior to 21, it works great.

Comment: I think ViewCompat.setElevation(View view, float elevation)  actually does nothing in Android Kitkat, it's just for prevent error while building.

Answer (score 0):

```
 val zoom = resources.getFraction(...) // Your zoom fraction in %
override fun onFocusChanged(gainFocus: Boolean, direction: Int, previouslyFocusedRect: Rect?) {
    super.onFocusChanged(gainFocus, direction, previouslyFocusedRect)
    val viewPropertyAnimator: ViewPropertyAnimator
    val f: Float
    if(gainFocus) {
        tvAppName.visibility = VISIBLE
        f = this.zoom;
        viewPropertyAnimator = animate().z(2.0f).scaleX(this.zoom);
        
    } else {
        tvAppName.visibility = INVISIBLE
        ivAppIcon.strokeWidth = 0f
        f = 1.0f;
        viewPropertyAnimator = animate().z(0.0f).scaleX(1.0f);
    }
    viewPropertyAnimator.scaleY(f).duration = 150;
}
```

You can add this sample code to any layout to achieve desired effect.

Answer (score -2):

You need to do it the old way you do with normal ViewGroups, overriding the draw order of children. This example forces the first view to always be drawn last - you need to customize for your use case.

```
public TopForcingRecyclerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    setChildrenDrawingOrderEnabled(true);
}

@Override protected int getChildDrawingOrder(int childCount, int i) {
    if (i >= childCount - 1) return 0; 
    //when asked for the last view to draw, answer ZERO
    else return i + 1;
    //when asked for the i-th view to draw, answer "the next one"
}
```

Pay attention to off by one errors.