# How to scale up Recycler View center item while scrolling in android?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I need to always highlight the center item in the recycler view while scrolling by scaling up.

Comment: Update your question with a much more specific question and add some code of what you have so far.  You will get down votes with this question and lose your ability to ask questions again.

Comment: something like this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29487382/scale-up-item-in-recyclerview-to-overlaps-2-adjacent-items-android ... I need to highlight center item in horizontal recycler view.Is there ny method please guide me?

Answer (score 25):

You should follow this code, this helped me to scale up the center item in recycler view.

```
public class CenterZoomLayoutManager extends LinearLayoutManager {

    private final float mShrinkAmount = 0.15f;
    private final float mShrinkDistance = 0.9f;

    public CenterZoomLayoutManager(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CenterZoomLayoutManager(Context context, int orientation, boolean reverseLayout) {
        super(context, orientation, reverseLayout);
    }

    @Override
    public int scrollVerticallyBy(int dy, RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, RecyclerView.State state) {
        int orientation = getOrientation();
        if (orientation == VERTICAL) {
            int scrolled = super.scrollVerticallyBy(dy, recycler, state);
            float midpoint = getHeight() / 2.f;
            float d0 = 0.f;
            float d1 = mShrinkDistance * midpoint;
            float s0 = 1.f;
            float s1 = 1.f - mShrinkAmount;
            for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++) {
                View child = getChildAt(i);
                float childMidpoint =
                        (getDecoratedBottom(child) + getDecoratedTop(child)) / 2.f;
                float d = Math.min(d1, Math.abs(midpoint - childMidpoint));
                float scale = s0 + (s1 - s0) * (d - d0) / (d1 - d0);
                child.setScaleX(scale);
                child.setScaleY(scale);
            }
            return scrolled;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int scrollHorizontallyBy(int dx, RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, RecyclerView.State state) {
        int orientation = getOrientation();
        if (orientation == HORIZONTAL) {
            int scrolled = super.scrollHorizontallyBy(dx, recycler, state);

            float midpoint = getWidth() / 2.f;
            float d0 = 0.f;
            float d1 = mShrinkDistance * midpoint;
            float s0 = 1.f;
            float s1 = 1.f - mShrinkAmount;
            for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++) {
                View child = getChildAt(i);
                float childMidpoint =
                        (getDecoratedRight(child) + getDecoratedLeft(child)) / 2.f;
                float d = Math.min(d1, Math.abs(midpoint - childMidpoint));
                float scale = s0 + (s1 - s0) * (d - d0) / (d1 - d0);
                child.setScaleX(scale);
                child.setScaleY(scale);
            }
            return scrolled;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }

    }
}
```

center horizontal view
[image]

Comment: Thanks for perfect solution. But how to apply resize to first element on RecyclerView init?

Comment: @fHate how did you apply it to first item

Comment: Also this does not apply in the last item.

Comment: thanks for this amazing solution, the problem is the middle item won't get bigger after creating the recycler view so when you scroll it for a bit all the item change their size immediately and it makes a bad view for the user, is it possible to shrink items with animations? or change the size right after creating a recycler view and adapter?

Comment: Hello, How to init center zoom first time? Manual scrolling the adapter to x position and center zoom the element

Comment: this is a good solution yet have a problem is some situation. If I have a margin between each item, scaling items make the margin become bigger or smaller. This is quite apparent in some situation.

Comment: On 1st and last item only, I can get a glance of next/last element and in between I don't see the next and last elements.

Answer (score 12):

I slimmed down that solution and added the initial resize during `onLayoutComplete`.  I didn't need vertical scrolling, so I took that part out.

```
class CenterZoomLinearLayoutManager(
    context: Context,
    private val mShrinkDistance: Float = 0.9f,
    val mShrinkAmount: Float = 0.15f
) : LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false) {

    override fun onLayoutCompleted(state: RecyclerView.State?) {
        super.onLayoutCompleted(state)
        scaleChildren()
    }

    override fun scrollHorizontallyBy(dx: Int, recycler: RecyclerView.Recycler?, state: RecyclerView.State?): Int {
        return if (orientation == HORIZONTAL) {
            super.scrollHorizontallyBy(dx, recycler, state).also { scaleChildren() }
        } else {
            0
        }
    }

    private fun scaleChildren() {
        val midpoint = width / 2f
        val d1 = mShrinkDistance * midpoint
        for (i in 0 until childCount) {
            val child = getChildAt(i) as View
            val d = Math.min(d1, Math.abs(midpoint - (getDecoratedRight(child) + getDecoratedLeft(child)) / 2f))
            val scale = 1f - mShrinkAmount * d / d1
            child.scaleX = scale
            child.scaleY = scale
        }
    }
}
```

See https://github.com/pcholt/toy-card-carousel

Comment: @fHate I think this is what you're looking for?

Comment: good example but unfourtunatly the first time the item is not properly center

Comment: This works well! In order to make it work for the first and last item as well, we just need to add an item decoration to add extra space at the beginning and at then. Like this: https://gist.github.com/dadouf/38f5816447c78d020d894c5c7c0c0fae

Comment: What if I want to scale only a child of my view. Eg. a textview of the item, how can I do that ? Currently stuck on that problem.

Comment: how can I reduce the margin between the items? @Anarchofascist

Answer (score 1):

As an addendum to [Mayank Garg's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46924548/172690) and the comments it has saying that *it does not work for the first or last items*, this happens when you are using this class and **also adding extra padding** to the list at the beginning and end in order for the first item to appear already centered. In these situations, functions like `getDecoratedRight()` and `getDecoratedLeft()` will include the extra padding in the sizes they return. This messes up the calculation of the view's midpoint, and hence it *won't work* for the first and last items.

A solution to this is to detect if the layout manager is displaying the beginning of the list or not, and use a conditional to use a different calculation which uses one of the decorated *anchors* as origin but then uses the view's halved width in order to find the midpoint.

In other words, in Mayank's code you have:

```
childMidpoint =
   (getDecoratedRight(child) + getDecoratedLeft(child)) / 2.f;
```

You can replace this with something similar to the following:

```
if (findFirstVisibleItemPosition() == 0 && i == 0) {
   childMidPoint = getDecoratedRight(child) - child.getWidth() / 2.f;
} else {
   childMidPoint = getDecoratedLeft(child) + child.getWidth() / 2.f;
}
```

In other words, this checks that the first child view is, or isn't, the first item in the adapter, and if so uses either the left or right *decorated* horizontal position to calculate the midpoint by subtracting or adding the item's halved width.

Another simpler alternative is:

```
childMidpoint = child.getX() + child.getWidth() / 2.0f
```

But then again, you need to test if this fits other *constraints* you may have on your layout/views, since there is probably a reason Mayank used `getDecoratedLeft()` instead of `getX()`.

Answer (score 1):

This method worked for me, and the problem I solved was that when RecyclerView was created, the items on the scale were not applied to them, and let me also say that the numbers I used were based on my needs, and you based on Need to adjust the scale yourself

```
public class CenterZoomLayoutManager extends LinearLayoutManager {
private final float mShrinkAmount = 0.25f;
private final float mShrinkDistance = 2.0f;

public CenterZoomLayoutManager(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public CenterZoomLayoutManager(Context context, int orientation, boolean reverseLayout) {
    super(context, orientation, reverseLayout);
}

public CenterZoomLayoutManager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
}

@Override
public void onLayoutCompleted(RecyclerView.State state) {
    super.onLayoutCompleted(state);
    scaleChild();
}

@Override
public int scrollHorizontallyBy(int dx, RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, RecyclerView.State state) {
    int orientation = getOrientation();
    if (orientation == HORIZONTAL) {
        scaleChild();
        return super.scrollHorizontallyBy(dx, recycler, state);
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

private void scaleChild() {
    float midPoint = getWidth() / 2.f;
    float d1 = mShrinkDistance * midPoint;
    for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++) {
        View child = getChildAt(i);
        float childMidPoint = (getDecoratedRight(child) + getDecoratedLeft(child)) / 2f;
        float d = Math.min(d1, Math.abs(midPoint - childMidPoint));
        float scale = 1.05f - mShrinkAmount * d / d1;
        child.setScaleY(scale);
        child.setScaleX(scale);
    }
}
```

}

Be sure to call the scaleChild method in `onLayoutCompleted`. To apply the scale to items when the RecyclerView layout is created. Not just when scrolling. This is an important point

```
@Override
public void onLayoutCompleted(RecyclerView.State state) {
    super.onLayoutCompleted(state);
    scaleChild();
}
```

The next important point is to use the `scaleChild()` method before `returning super.scrollHorizontallyBy (dx, recycler, state)` . Call. Until scrolling is done. The scale is done each time on the item

```
@Override
public int scrollHorizontallyBy(int dx, RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, RecyclerView.State state) {
    int orientation = getOrientation();
    if (orientation == HORIZONTAL) {
        scaleChild();
        return super.scrollHorizontallyBy(dx, recycler, state);
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Eventually, this became my program output
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well, following Anarchofascist and Mayank, just add this override at the biggining of Mayank code to make the effect work with the first element.

```
@Override
public void onLayoutCompleted(RecyclerView.State state) {
    super.onLayoutCompleted(state);

    //aqui ele executa o codigo no estado inicial, originalmente ele nao aplicava no inicio
    //este codigo é em horizontal. Para usar em vertical apagar e copiar o codigo
    int orientation = getOrientation();
    if (orientation == HORIZONTAL) {

        float midpoint = getWidth() / 2.f;
        float d0 = 0.f;
        float d1 = mShrinkDistance * midpoint;
        float s0 = 1.f;
        float s1 = 1.f - mShrinkAmount;
        for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++) {
            View child = getChildAt(i);
            float childMidpoint =
                    (getDecoratedRight(child) + getDecoratedLeft(child)) / 2.f;
            float d = Math.min(d1, Math.abs(midpoint - childMidpoint));
            float scale = s0 + (s1 - s0) * (d - d0) / (d1 - d0);
            child.setScaleX(scale);
            child.setScaleY(scale);
        }

    } else {

        float midpoint = getHeight() / 2.f;
        float d0 = 0.f;
        float d1 = mShrinkDistance * midpoint;
        float s0 = 1.f;
        float s1 = 1.f - mShrinkAmount;
        for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++) {
            View child = getChildAt(i);
            float childMidpoint =
                    (getDecoratedBottom(child) + getDecoratedTop(child)) / 2.f;
            float d = Math.min(d1, Math.abs(midpoint - childMidpoint));
            float scale = s0 + (s1 - s0) * (d - d0) / (d1 - d0);
            child.setScaleX(scale);
            child.setScaleY(scale);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: @fHate this is what you were looking for?