# RecyclerView Center Item Larger than others and varying size when scrolling

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I would like to make a horizontal RecyclerView like this: (**ignore white circle in the centre**)

[image]

Here the major things are scaling the center item and scaling the outgoing item as well. Can I have some reference point as how can I achieve such a view?

Comment: use transfrom animation into recyclerview items

Comment: @Niceumang Can I have some reference?

Comment: @ParasSidhu have you check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32823713/how-to-scale-up-recycler-view-center-item-while-scrolling-in-android

Comment: @NileshRathod Looks good. Let me check. Thanks :)

Comment: @ParasSidhu try this one also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33290906/3973113

Comment: @Ben This seems to be for Android TV, will this work on mobile?

Comment: Have a look at https://medium.com/@supahsoftware/custom-android-views-carousel-recyclerview-7b9318d23e9a

Comment: @ManoharReddy Cool, that worked!
NileshRathod That solution doesn't work unless user scrolls a bit initially.

Answer (score 1):

You can use below library for this I have already use this library for same

https://github.com/Azoft/CarouselLayoutManager

Add **CarouselLayoutManager** and set recycler view property as per below

```
CarouselLayoutManager layoutManager = new CarouselLayoutManager(CarouselLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, true);
layoutManager.setPostLayoutListener(new CarouselZoomPostLayoutListener());

yourAdapter = new YourAdapter(arrayList, context);
binding.rvGame.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
binding.rvGame.setHasFixedSize(true);
binding.rvGame.setAdapter(yourAdapter);
binding.rvGame.addOnScrollListener(new CenterScrollListener());
```

I hope this can help you!

Thank You.

Comment: This didn't work for me. Items never appeared. I know that for this, RecyclerView has to be of fixed size but somehow no items appeared and I followed the same way as above.

Comment: @ParasSidhu May be problem in your code I was already achieved this thing using same and it's working perfectly.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, here it's: https://gist.github.com/sidhuparas/0fa91ce7c02acb8e7c9bd72ad30e01d3
No items appear. I tried with normal layout manager and its showing the items so there should not be anything wrong with anything else