# How to highlight the center element in Horizontal ScrollView or RecycleView?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to develop a horizontal scroll view where all the days will be scrollable and the middle element will be selected and highlighted. Is there any method in the ScrollView to detect center cell elements?
[image]

Comment: Using  RecyclerView is a good option

Comment: Follow link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32823713/how-to-scale-up-recycler-view-center-item-while-scrolling-in-android