# Required Horizontal ScrollView Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I need help designing such horizontal scrolling view. I tried using both ViewPager and Horizontal Scroll View but I was not able to get a view with two small size images left and right side, the centre one I was able to design.

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Hope this one helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29487382/scale-up-item-in-recyclerview-to-overlaps-2-adjacent-items-android you

Answer (score 0):

Use recyclerview. Set layout manager as

```
mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);        
LinearLayoutManager mLayoyrManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoyrManager);
```